# Centering all fields in Anki (HTML)

Tags: html, css, anki

For the life of me I can't figure out why nothing will centre.

[image: Screenshot]
This image explains better than I could about what I want.

I want to centre all fields without changing which way around the kanji appear (For some reason the `{{Expression}}` field keeps flipping when I try to centre.

http://pastebin.com/PqEN9xMT

Comment: It seems I can only move it with padding-right and things like that. Anything else seems to flip it from vertical text.

Answer (score 2):

In your Templates wrap the Expression field with a div, give the div a class, and then center it with css styling.

If you want the absolute center of the main window try:

**Front Template:**

```
<div class='center-me'>
    {Front}
</div>
```

**Styling:**

```
.center-me {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
```